# Como incluir colunas em um data.frame?

Tags: r, data.frame

Considere o seguinte `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a","b"), y=c(1,2))
```

Como incluir uma nova coluna, digamos, `z = c(1,2)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Além do:

```
df$z <- c(1,2)
```

Outras maneiras simples de adicionar apenas uma coluna são:

`df["z"] <- c(1,2)
df[["z"]] <- c(1,2)
df[,"z"] <- c(1,2)`

Da mesma forma, você pode removê-la com:

`df$z <- NULL`

E funciona com todas as outras formas:

```
df["z"] <- NULL
df[["z"]] <- NULL
df[,"z"] <- NULL
```

Answer (score 8):

Talvez a forma mais simples seja:

```
df$z <- c(1,2)
df
  x y z
1 a 1 1
2 b 2 2
```

Uma forma que não é muito conhecida, ma é interessante saber que existe, é utilizando a função `within()`. Criando um vetor `w = c(3,4)` como exemplo:

```
df <- within(df, w <- c(3,4))
df
  x y z w
1 a 1 1 3
2 b 2 2 4
```

Answer (score 5):

Também pode usar a função transform.

```
df <- transform(df, z=c(1,2),  w=c(3,4))

  x y z w
1 a 1 1 3
2 b 2 2 4
```

Answer (score 1):

A função `mutate()` do `dplyr` também pode ser uma opção:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, z=c(1,2))

  x y z
1 a 1 1
2 b 2 2
```